# Docker-compose env var missing after save and load

Tags: python, docker, flask, environment-variables, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy a flask instance with `docker-compose` based on 
this config :

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  flask:
    container_name: myproject
    image: myproject
    build: .
    env_file: dev.env
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

**dev.env**

```
FLASK_HOST=0.0.0.0
FLASK_PORT=5000
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
CMD python ./app/run.py
EXPOSE ${FLASK_PORT}
```

Everything works fine locally, but when I try to load the image backup and run it in a container on another machine, I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app/run.py", line 10, in <module>
    port = int(os.environ.get("FLASK_PORT"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

It seems that there are no more environment variables. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Are you running on another machine using `docker run` or `docker-compose up`?

Comment: I build locally `docker-compose build` and then I save the image `docker save myproject -o myproject.tar`. After that, I export the backup file to another machine to load and run the image `docker image load -i myproject.tar && docker run -P myproject`.

Comment: env-file does not pass to another machine. See my answer.

Comment: AFAICT environment variables are injected into the container at runtime and not build time. When you build your image by running `docker-compose build`, environment variables are not injected until `docker-compose run`

Comment: That's what I missed.. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic in `docker-compose.yml`, it's just a wrap-up of Docker's commands.

For your case, the final command that starts up the container is something like:

```
docker run --env-file=xxx ...
```

This env-file never made its way to transfer to another machine.